# Grails quartz plugin breaks on upgrade from mysql 5.5 to mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql, grails, quartz-scheduler

I am using the Quartz plugin:

```
compile ":quartz:1.0.2"
```

In my BuildConfig.groovy. This appears to be the latest version of Quartz to use.

I am trying to upgrade to MySQL 5.6.19 and on startup I get the following error from Quartz:

```
Message: Couldn't acquire next trigger: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=1' at line 1
```

This appears to be a breaking change between MySql 5.5 and MySql 5.6.

Is there a fix for Quartz or a workaround to get around this when using MySql 5.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is related to the JDBC driver. Upgrading from 5.1.6 to a more recent version 5.1.31 solved the issue.

[Quartz JDBCJobStore problems with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259524/quartz-jdbcjobstore-problems-with-mysql)